# Is there anyway of telling if a landscape window is 90 or -90 degress without turning it?

Tags: jquery, mobile, orientation

I've been looking around for a solution like:

```
$(window).on("orientationchange",function(){
    if(window.orientation == 90) {
        console.log('This is 90 degrees');
    } else if(window.orientation == -90) {
        console.log('This is -90 degrees');
    } else {
        console.log('This is portrait');
    }
});
```

But the problem is I want to detect which way the orientation is without having to turn the screen. I'd like the screen to load and to already know it's either at 90 degrees or set to -90 degrees. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Please check following code which will work on page load and orientation change,

```
  <script>
  function changeOrientation()
  {
    switch(window.orientation) 
    {  
      case -90:
       alert('landscape -90');
        break; 
      case 90:
        alert('landscape 90');
        break; 
      default:
        alert('portrait');
        break; 
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('orientationchange', changeOrientation);

  // on page load call
  changeOrientation();
  </script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work. I need a solution without an event handler being used to determine if the window has been turned.

Comment: You can remove "window.addEventListener('orientationchange', changeOrientation);"  and call "changeOrientation()" function wherever you require. I have verified it shows alert while page is loading.

Comment: OK thanks, but, will this only work if the screen moves?

Comment: My posted code will work for both case when page load and when orientation change . if you require only on page load you can remove "eventListener" line. or if you require only orientation change you can remove  "changeOrientation();" call from page load.